# debug apk is not generating even after successfull gradle build in android studio

Tags: android, debugging, apk

I am trying to generate debug apk from android studio, but even after successfull build, apk is not generated. Even apk folder itself is not generating in outputs. its showing error
"Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed.
Installation failed due to: 'Invalid File: D:\MyProject\app\build\outputs\apk\Standard\debug\mobile-Standard-debug.apk'".
 I am able to generate signed apk and debug bundle as well.
Any suggestions appreciated. I have tried cleaning, rebuild, invalidate cache and restart and all every possibilities

Comment: Run `./gradlew assembleDebug --debug`  or  `./gradlew assembleDebug --info` at the terminal and see if you can detect what goes wrong during the build.

Comment: what version of AS do you have

Comment: I am using android studio 3.5.2

Comment: try rebuild,rebuild also creates the debug apk. Have you tried this ?

Comment: Now, I found that debug apk is generating in other path, which i gave for release apk. How can I change the debug apk generation path?